# comparing the complexity of nested for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, time-complexity

How is the time complexity of the following loops:

```
for(conditions) {
    if() {
        for() {

        }
    }
}
```

different from the time complexity of the following loops:

```
for () {
    for() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, what? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then edit your question

Comment: We need to know a lot more about the conditions...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how many times the `if` condition evaluates to `true`, which affects the number of times the inner loop is executed.

Let's assume the outer and inner loops have `O(n)` iterations.

If it evaluates to `true` a constant number of times, the inner loop will be executed a constant number of times, so the total running time will be linear.

For example, here the inner loop will be executed `3` times, so the total running time is `O(n)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i < 3) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // do some constant time work
        }
    }
}
```

If it evaluates to `true` a number of times proportional to `n` (for example, half the iterations of the outer loop, or a third of the iterations of the outer loop, etc...), the total running time will be quadratic, which is the same as two nested for loops without the condition.

For example, here the inner loop will be executed `n/2` times, so the total running time is `O(n^2)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // do some constant time work
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming the evaluation of the `if` statement's condition requires a constant time. Otherwise, the answer may be different.

Comment: assuming the worst case scenario in the first code that is the if statement will run n times then will both of them have the same complexity?

Comment: @harman yes, assuming evaluating the condition of the if statement doesn't have a large time complexity.